# How is the null reference in Scala justified?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, null, nullable

Liskov substitution principle:
B is a subtype of A iff anything one can do with A one can do with B.
So why is Null a subtype of all classes in Scala even though by the above definition it isn't a subtype of any class? Couldn't Null have been defined as implementing all possible methods, each returning null? What are the reasons Null was defined the way it is in Scala?

Comment: Since `null` is unavoidable on the JVM and is supposed to replace any reference value, the only place to put it is just above `Nothing`. Where else? `Nothing` doesn't violate LSP as there is no instance of it, `Null` does because of `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Null is pretty much unavoidable on the JVM. References can be null. Scala can't stop that.

All Scala did was include Java's null into the unified type system. It exists for Java interop, nothing more. Null was wrong in Java, and it's also wrong in Scala.

Yes, null references are the ultimate LSP violation. No, there's no way to fix that. Evaluating method invocations on null to `null` instead of to throwing `NullPointerException` wouldn't be any more or less correct, just equally nonsensical.

There's really nothing interesting to see here. Wrap anything nullable in `Option(...)`, forget about this dark pit of incorrectness, and move on.

Comment: If null.someMethod(someParameters) returned null, null could be seen as an implementation of the superclass where all method bodies are empty. To my mind this would make great sense considering that one can return a dummy implementation of a class in any case.

Comment: For most methods, returning null would violate their contract. Your suggestion isn't more correct than any other implementation, including the one that the JVM has (throwing NullPointerException). Also, again remember this is the JVM. Null cannot inhabit all types (namely, the primitives) so implementing your version would require boxing all primitive return values.

Comment: LSP involves considering what the methods do, not merely whether they throw exceptions.

Comment: Theoretically where a primitive return type is specified a default value would be used. Basically null would become shorthand for writing an anonymous dummy class implementation. We wouldn't need to worry about JVM inside Scala since null wouldn't ever be used - behind the scenes we would translate null to a dummy class implementation. Java interoperability would still require automatically added null checks between Java and Scala though.

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't Null have been defined as implementing all possible methods, each returning null?

No. 1. Methods returning primitive types can't return null; 2. the only reason Scala has `null` is because JVM has it; and the JVM `null` doesn't behave this way. This would require basically adding an `if` before *every* method call unless the compiler can *prove* the receiver isn't null, which it normally can't.